# What is the policy on undelete?

Tags: discussion

Without getting into a specific post, what's the policy on undelete?

When should a user nominate a post to be un-deleted?

How can the proposer / nominator state the reason (it doesn't give a menu when pressed)?

Comment: In the absence of a community policy, the SE guidelines apply. Undelete when you believe the deletion should not be done as it brings more harm than good to the site?

Comment: and/or when the post has been since updated to match the quality criteria of the site.

Comment: Also, being an "undelete" review queue unavailable, you will have to resort to chat and/or a meta post to get enough undelete votes (and contrary to repoen ones, you have the upper hand, since no "leave deleted" votes exist)